# How to post website updates to Facebook page

Tags: facebook

I run a PHP-coded website with user submitted material and I am looking for a way that anytime new content is added to the site a post appears on my Facebook page (not profile). I used to be able to do this with the secret Facebook posting email but Facebook has quietly killed that feature. How can I do this in PHP?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/page/feed#publish

Comment: thank you, are there any code examples I can look at? I am not really good enough a developer to understand APIs and such